# C++ - Slot Machine Output - I need a simpler way to pass random string arrays into a function

Tags: c++

I'm working on a slot machine project for school and I've come up with this code for spitting out the images randomly. I feel like the entire `randomCheck()` function is a huge waste of space. Can anyone enlighten me how to do this more efficiently?

It's a lot of code... sorry about that. Please let me know if you need any more information from me.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<random>
#include<vector>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int nuM;
int getNum(int min, int max)
{
    nuM = min + (rand() % (max - min) + 1);
    return nuM;
}

HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
COORD CursorPosition;

void gotoXY(int x, int y, string text)
{
    CursorPosition.X = x;
    CursorPosition.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(console, CursorPosition);

    cout << text;
}

vector<int>v(9);

string Clover[] =
{ "    .-.-.     "
,"   (     )    "
," .-.\\ : /.-. "
,"(   . : .   ) "
," (   /|\\   ) "
,"  `\"` | `\"` "
,"      ~       "
};

string Seven[] =
{ "  _________   "
,"  |____   /   "
,"      /  /    "
,"     /  /     "
,"    /  /      "
,"   /  /       "
,"  /__/        "
};

string Money[] =
{ "    ___       "
,"   _\\ /_      "
,"  /     \\    "
,"  |     |     "
,"  | $$$ |     "
,"  |     |     "
,"  \\_____/    "
};

string Diamond[] =
{ "     _        "
,"    / \\      "
,"   /   \\     "
,"  /     \\    "
,"  \\     /    "
,"   \\   /     "
,"    \\_/      "
};

string Bolt[] =
{ "        __    "
,"      _/ /    "
,"     /__/     "
,"   _//        "
,"  /_/         "
," //           "
,"/'            "
};

string Cherry[] =
{ "-._.-(`-.__`-.  "
,"      \\    `~~`"
," .--./ \\       "
,"/#   \\  \\.--. "
,"\\    /  /#   \\"
," '--'   \\    / "
,"         '--'   "
};

string wtf1[7];
string wtf2[7];
string wtf3[7];
string wtf4[7];
string wtf5[7];
string wtf6[7];
string wtf7[7];
string wtf8[7];
string wtf9[7];

void slotMachine(string a[], string b[], string c[], string d[], string e[], string f[], string g[], string h[], string i[])
{
    for (int y = 0; y<7; y++)
    {
        gotoXY(20, 1 + y, a[y]);
    }

    for (int y = 0; y<7; y++)
    {
        gotoXY(45, 1 + y, b[y]);
    }

    for (int y = 0; y<7; y++)
    {
        gotoXY(70, 1 + y, c[y]);
    }
    //second line
    for (int y = 0; y<7; y++)
    {
        gotoXY(20, 10 + y, d[y]);
    }

    for (int y = 0; y<7; y++)
    {
        gotoXY(45, 10 + y, e[y]);
    }

    for (int y = 0; y<7; y++)
    {
        gotoXY(70, 10 + y, f[y]);
    }
    // third line
    for (int y = 0; y<7; y++)
    {
        gotoXY(20, 20 + y, g[y]);
    }

    for (int y = 0; y<7; y++)
    {
        gotoXY(45, 20 + y, h[y]);
    }

    for (int y = 0; y<7; y++)
    {
        gotoXY(70, 20 + y, i[y]);
    }
}

void randomCheck()
{
    //a1
    getNum(0, 6);
    if (nuM == 1)
    {
        v[0] = 1;
        wtf1[0] = Seven[0];
        wtf1[1] = Seven[1];
        wtf1[2] = Seven[2];
        wtf1[3] = Seven[3];
        wtf1[4] = Seven[4];
        wtf1[5] = Seven[5];
        wtf1[6] = Seven[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 2)
    {
        v[0] = 2;
        wtf1[0] = Money[0];
        wtf1[1] = Money[1];
        wtf1[2] = Money[2];
        wtf1[3] = Money[3];
        wtf1[4] = Money[4];
        wtf1[5] = Money[5];
        wtf1[6] = Money[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 3)
    {
        v[0] = 3;
        wtf1[0] = Diamond[0];
        wtf1[1] = Diamond[1];
        wtf1[2] = Diamond[2];
        wtf1[3] = Diamond[3];
        wtf1[4] = Diamond[4];
        wtf1[5] = Diamond[5];
        wtf1[6] = Diamond[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 4)
    {
        v[0] = 4;
        wtf1[0] = Bolt[0];
        wtf1[1] = Bolt[1];
        wtf1[2] = Bolt[2];
        wtf1[3] = Bolt[3];
        wtf1[4] = Bolt[4];
        wtf1[5] = Bolt[5];
        wtf1[6] = Bolt[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 5)
    {
        v[0] = 5;
        wtf1[0] = Cherry[0];
        wtf1[1] = Cherry[1];
        wtf1[2] = Cherry[2];
        wtf1[3] = Cherry[3];
        wtf1[4] = Cherry[4];
        wtf1[5] = Cherry[5];
        wtf1[6] = Cherry[6];
    }
    else
    {
        v[0] = 6;
        wtf1[0] = Clover[0];
        wtf1[1] = Clover[1];
        wtf1[2] = Clover[2];
        wtf1[3] = Clover[3];
        wtf1[4] = Clover[4];
        wtf1[5] = Clover[5];
        wtf1[6] = Clover[6];
    }

    //a2
    getNum(0, 6);
    if (nuM == 1)
    {
        v[1] = 1;
        wtf2[0] = Seven[0];
        wtf2[1] = Seven[1];
        wtf2[2] = Seven[2];
        wtf2[3] = Seven[3];
        wtf2[4] = Seven[4];
        wtf2[5] = Seven[5];
        wtf2[6] = Seven[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 2)
    {
        v[1] = 2;
        wtf2[0] = Money[0];
        wtf2[1] = Money[1];
        wtf2[2] = Money[2];
        wtf2[3] = Money[3];
        wtf2[4] = Money[4];
        wtf2[5] = Money[5];
        wtf2[6] = Money[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 3)
    {
        v[1] = 3;
        wtf2[0] = Diamond[0];
        wtf2[1] = Diamond[1];
        wtf2[2] = Diamond[2];
        wtf2[3] = Diamond[3];
        wtf2[4] = Diamond[4];
        wtf2[5] = Diamond[5];
        wtf2[6] = Diamond[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 4)
    {
        v[1] = 4;
        wtf2[0] = Bolt[0];
        wtf2[1] = Bolt[1];
        wtf2[2] = Bolt[2];
        wtf2[3] = Bolt[3];
        wtf2[4] = Bolt[4];
        wtf2[5] = Bolt[5];
        wtf2[6] = Bolt[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 5)
    {
        v[1] = 5;
        wtf2[0] = Cherry[0];
        wtf2[1] = Cherry[1];
        wtf2[2] = Cherry[2];
        wtf2[3] = Cherry[3];
        wtf2[4] = Cherry[4];
        wtf2[5] = Cherry[5];
        wtf2[6] = Cherry[6];
    }
    else
    {
        v[1] = 6;
        wtf2[0] = Clover[0];
        wtf2[1] = Clover[1];
        wtf2[2] = Clover[2];
        wtf2[3] = Clover[3];
        wtf2[4] = Clover[4];
        wtf2[5] = Clover[5];
        wtf2[6] = Clover[6];
    }

    //a3
    getNum(0, 6);
    if (nuM == 1)
    {
        v[2] = 1;
        wtf3[0] = Seven[0];
        wtf3[1] = Seven[1];
        wtf3[2] = Seven[2];
        wtf3[3] = Seven[3];
        wtf3[4] = Seven[4];
        wtf3[5] = Seven[5];
        wtf3[6] = Seven[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 2)
    {
        v[2] = 2;
        wtf3[0] = Money[0];
        wtf3[1] = Money[1];
        wtf3[2] = Money[2];
        wtf3[3] = Money[3];
        wtf3[4] = Money[4];
        wtf3[5] = Money[5];
        wtf3[6] = Money[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 3)
    {
        v[2] = 3;
        wtf3[0] = Diamond[0];
        wtf3[1] = Diamond[1];
        wtf3[2] = Diamond[2];
        wtf3[3] = Diamond[3];
        wtf3[4] = Diamond[4];
        wtf3[5] = Diamond[5];
        wtf3[6] = Diamond[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 4)
    {
        v[2] = 4;
        wtf3[0] = Bolt[0];
        wtf3[1] = Bolt[1];
        wtf3[2] = Bolt[2];
        wtf3[3] = Bolt[3];
        wtf3[4] = Bolt[4];
        wtf3[5] = Bolt[5];
        wtf3[6] = Bolt[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 5)
    {
        v[2] = 5;
        wtf3[0] = Cherry[0];
        wtf3[1] = Cherry[1];
        wtf3[2] = Cherry[2];
        wtf3[3] = Cherry[3];
        wtf3[4] = Cherry[4];
        wtf3[5] = Cherry[5];
        wtf3[6] = Cherry[6];
    }
    else
    {
        v[2] = 6;
        wtf3[0] = Clover[0];
        wtf3[1] = Clover[1];
        wtf3[2] = Clover[2];
        wtf3[3] = Clover[3];
        wtf3[4] = Clover[4];
        wtf3[5] = Clover[5];
        wtf3[6] = Clover[6];
    }

    //b1
    getNum(0, 6);
    if (nuM == 1)
    {
        v[3] = 1;
        wtf4[0] = Seven[0];
        wtf4[1] = Seven[1];
        wtf4[2] = Seven[2];
        wtf4[3] = Seven[3];
        wtf4[4] = Seven[4];
        wtf4[5] = Seven[5];
        wtf4[6] = Seven[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 2)
    {
        v[3] = 2;
        wtf4[0] = Money[0];
        wtf4[1] = Money[1];
        wtf4[2] = Money[2];
        wtf4[3] = Money[3];
        wtf4[4] = Money[4];
        wtf4[5] = Money[5];
        wtf4[6] = Money[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 3)
    {
        v[3] = 3;
        wtf4[0] = Diamond[0];
        wtf4[1] = Diamond[1];
        wtf4[2] = Diamond[2];
        wtf4[3] = Diamond[3];
        wtf4[4] = Diamond[4];
        wtf4[5] = Diamond[5];
        wtf4[6] = Diamond[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 4)
    {
        v[3] = 4;
        wtf4[0] = Bolt[0];
        wtf4[1] = Bolt[1];
        wtf4[2] = Bolt[2];
        wtf4[3] = Bolt[3];
        wtf4[4] = Bolt[4];
        wtf4[5] = Bolt[5];
        wtf4[6] = Bolt[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 5)
    {
        v[3] = 5;
        wtf4[0] = Cherry[0];
        wtf4[1] = Cherry[1];
        wtf4[2] = Cherry[2];
        wtf4[3] = Cherry[3];
        wtf4[4] = Cherry[4];
        wtf4[5] = Cherry[5];
        wtf4[6] = Cherry[6];
    }
    else
    {
        v[3] = 6;
        wtf4[0] = Clover[0];
        wtf4[1] = Clover[1];
        wtf4[2] = Clover[2];
        wtf4[3] = Clover[3];
        wtf4[4] = Clover[4];
        wtf4[5] = Clover[5];
        wtf4[6] = Clover[6];
    }

    //b2
    getNum(0, 6);
    if (nuM == 1)
    {
        v[4] = 1;
        wtf5[0] = Seven[0];
        wtf5[1] = Seven[1];
        wtf5[2] = Seven[2];
        wtf5[3] = Seven[3];
        wtf5[4] = Seven[4];
        wtf5[5] = Seven[5];
        wtf5[6] = Seven[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 2)
    {
        v[4] = 2;
        wtf5[0] = Money[0];
        wtf5[1] = Money[1];
        wtf5[2] = Money[2];
        wtf5[3] = Money[3];
        wtf5[4] = Money[4];
        wtf5[5] = Money[5];
        wtf5[6] = Money[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 3)
    {
        v[4] = 3;
        wtf5[0] = Diamond[0];
        wtf5[1] = Diamond[1];
        wtf5[2] = Diamond[2];
        wtf5[3] = Diamond[3];
        wtf5[4] = Diamond[4];
        wtf5[5] = Diamond[5];
        wtf5[6] = Diamond[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 4)
    {
        v[4] = 4;
        wtf5[0] = Bolt[0];
        wtf5[1] = Bolt[1];
        wtf5[2] = Bolt[2];
        wtf5[3] = Bolt[3];
        wtf5[4] = Bolt[4];
        wtf5[5] = Bolt[5];
        wtf5[6] = Bolt[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 5)
    {
        v[4] = 5;
        wtf5[0] = Cherry[0];
        wtf5[1] = Cherry[1];
        wtf5[2] = Cherry[2];
        wtf5[3] = Cherry[3];
        wtf5[4] = Cherry[4];
        wtf5[5] = Cherry[5];
        wtf5[6] = Cherry[6];
    }
    else
    {
        v[4] = 6;
        wtf5[0] = Clover[0];
        wtf5[1] = Clover[1];
        wtf5[2] = Clover[2];
        wtf5[3] = Clover[3];
        wtf5[4] = Clover[4];
        wtf5[5] = Clover[5];
        wtf5[6] = Clover[6];
    }

    //b3
    getNum(0, 6);
    if (nuM == 1)
    {
        v[5] = 1;
        wtf6[0] = Seven[0];
        wtf6[1] = Seven[1];
        wtf6[2] = Seven[2];
        wtf6[3] = Seven[3];
        wtf6[4] = Seven[4];
        wtf6[5] = Seven[5];
        wtf6[6] = Seven[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 2)
    {
        v[5] = 2;
        wtf6[0] = Money[0];
        wtf6[1] = Money[1];
        wtf6[2] = Money[2];
        wtf6[3] = Money[3];
        wtf6[4] = Money[4];
        wtf6[5] = Money[5];
        wtf6[6] = Money[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 3)
    {
        v[5] = 3;
        wtf6[0] = Diamond[0];
        wtf6[1] = Diamond[1];
        wtf6[2] = Diamond[2];
        wtf6[3] = Diamond[3];
        wtf6[4] = Diamond[4];
        wtf6[5] = Diamond[5];
        wtf6[6] = Diamond[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 4)
    {
        v[5] = 4;
        wtf6[0] = Bolt[0];
        wtf6[1] = Bolt[1];
        wtf6[2] = Bolt[2];
        wtf6[3] = Bolt[3];
        wtf6[4] = Bolt[4];
        wtf6[5] = Bolt[5];
        wtf6[6] = Bolt[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 5)
    {
        v[5] = 5;
        wtf6[0] = Cherry[0];
        wtf6[1] = Cherry[1];
        wtf6[2] = Cherry[2];
        wtf6[3] = Cherry[3];
        wtf6[4] = Cherry[4];
        wtf6[5] = Cherry[5];
        wtf6[6] = Cherry[6];
    }
    else
    {
        v[5] = 6;
        wtf6[0] = Clover[0];
        wtf6[1] = Clover[1];
        wtf6[2] = Clover[2];
        wtf6[3] = Clover[3];
        wtf6[4] = Clover[4];
        wtf6[5] = Clover[5];
        wtf6[6] = Clover[6];
    }

    //c1
    getNum(0, 6);
    if (nuM == 1)
    {
        v[6] = 1;
        wtf7[0] = Seven[0];
        wtf7[1] = Seven[1];
        wtf7[2] = Seven[2];
        wtf7[3] = Seven[3];
        wtf7[4] = Seven[4];
        wtf7[5] = Seven[5];
        wtf7[6] = Seven[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 2)
    {
        v[6] = 2;
        wtf7[0] = Money[0];
        wtf7[1] = Money[1];
        wtf7[2] = Money[2];
        wtf7[3] = Money[3];
        wtf7[4] = Money[4];
        wtf7[5] = Money[5];
        wtf7[6] = Money[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 3)
    {
        v[6] = 3;
        wtf7[0] = Diamond[0];
        wtf7[1] = Diamond[1];
        wtf7[2] = Diamond[2];
        wtf7[3] = Diamond[3];
        wtf7[4] = Diamond[4];
        wtf7[5] = Diamond[5];
        wtf7[6] = Diamond[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 4)
    {
        v[6] = 4;
        wtf7[0] = Bolt[0];
        wtf7[1] = Bolt[1];
        wtf7[2] = Bolt[2];
        wtf7[3] = Bolt[3];
        wtf7[4] = Bolt[4];
        wtf7[5] = Bolt[5];
        wtf7[6] = Bolt[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 5)
    {
        v[6] = 5;
        wtf7[0] = Cherry[0];
        wtf7[1] = Cherry[1];
        wtf7[2] = Cherry[2];
        wtf7[3] = Cherry[3];
        wtf7[4] = Cherry[4];
        wtf7[5] = Cherry[5];
        wtf7[6] = Cherry[6];
    }
    else
    {
        v[6] = 6;
        wtf7[0] = Clover[0];
        wtf7[1] = Clover[1];
        wtf7[2] = Clover[2];
        wtf7[3] = Clover[3];
        wtf7[4] = Clover[4];
        wtf7[5] = Clover[5];
        wtf7[6] = Clover[6];
    }

    //c2
    getNum(0, 6);
    if (nuM == 1)
    {
        v[7] = 1;
        wtf8[0] = Seven[0];
        wtf8[1] = Seven[1];
        wtf8[2] = Seven[2];
        wtf8[3] = Seven[3];
        wtf8[4] = Seven[4];
        wtf8[5] = Seven[5];
        wtf8[6] = Seven[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 2)
    {
        v[7] = 2;
        wtf8[0] = Money[0];
        wtf8[1] = Money[1];
        wtf8[2] = Money[2];
        wtf8[3] = Money[3];
        wtf8[4] = Money[4];
        wtf8[5] = Money[5];
        wtf8[6] = Money[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 3)
    {
        v[7] = 3;
        wtf8[0] = Diamond[0];
        wtf8[1] = Diamond[1];
        wtf8[2] = Diamond[2];
        wtf8[3] = Diamond[3];
        wtf8[4] = Diamond[4];
        wtf8[5] = Diamond[5];
        wtf8[6] = Diamond[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 4)
    {
        v[7] = 4;
        wtf8[0] = Bolt[0];
        wtf8[1] = Bolt[1];
        wtf8[2] = Bolt[2];
        wtf8[3] = Bolt[3];
        wtf8[4] = Bolt[4];
        wtf8[5] = Bolt[5];
        wtf8[6] = Bolt[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 5)
    {
        v[7] = 5;
        wtf8[0] = Cherry[0];
        wtf8[1] = Cherry[1];
        wtf8[2] = Cherry[2];
        wtf8[3] = Cherry[3];
        wtf8[4] = Cherry[4];
        wtf8[5] = Cherry[5];
        wtf8[6] = Cherry[6];
    }
    else
    {
        v[7] = 6;
        wtf8[0] = Clover[0];
        wtf8[1] = Clover[1];
        wtf8[2] = Clover[2];
        wtf8[3] = Clover[3];
        wtf8[4] = Clover[4];
        wtf8[5] = Clover[5];
        wtf8[6] = Clover[6];
    }

    //c3
    getNum(0, 6);
    if (nuM == 1)
    {
        v[8] = 1;
        wtf9[0] = Seven[0];
        wtf9[1] = Seven[1];
        wtf9[2] = Seven[2];
        wtf9[3] = Seven[3];
        wtf9[4] = Seven[4];
        wtf9[5] = Seven[5];
        wtf9[6] = Seven[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 2)
    {
        v[8] = 2;
        wtf9[0] = Money[0];
        wtf9[1] = Money[1];
        wtf9[2] = Money[2];
        wtf9[3] = Money[3];
        wtf9[4] = Money[4];
        wtf9[5] = Money[5];
        wtf9[6] = Money[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 3)
    {
        v[8] = 3;
        wtf9[0] = Diamond[0];
        wtf9[1] = Diamond[1];
        wtf9[2] = Diamond[2];
        wtf9[3] = Diamond[3];
        wtf9[4] = Diamond[4];
        wtf9[5] = Diamond[5];
        wtf9[6] = Diamond[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 4)
    {
        v[8] = 4;
        wtf9[0] = Bolt[0];
        wtf9[1] = Bolt[1];
        wtf9[2] = Bolt[2];
        wtf9[3] = Bolt[3];
        wtf9[4] = Bolt[4];
        wtf9[5] = Bolt[5];
        wtf9[6] = Bolt[6];
    }
    else if (nuM == 5)
    {
        v[8] = 5;
        wtf9[0] = Cherry[0];
        wtf9[1] = Cherry[1];
        wtf9[2] = Cherry[2];
        wtf9[3] = Cherry[3];
        wtf9[4] = Cherry[4];
        wtf9[5] = Cherry[5];
        wtf9[6] = Cherry[6];
    }
    else
    {
        v[8] = 6;
        wtf9[0] = Clover[0];
        wtf9[1] = Clover[1];
        wtf9[2] = Clover[2];
        wtf9[3] = Clover[3];
        wtf9[4] = Clover[4];
        wtf9[5] = Clover[5];
        wtf9[6] = Clover[6];
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    bool on = true;
    while (on)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            system("cls");
            randomCheck();
            slotMachine(wtf1, wtf2, wtf3, wtf4, wtf5, wtf6, wtf7, wtf8, wtf9);

        }
        system("pause");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions about improving code that already works should be done on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I highly recommend using a `switch` statement or a 3 dimensional array or vector.

Comment: You could eliminate the `gotoXY` function and calls by using a "raster" buffer.  Use a buffer that represents one row to be output.  Print one row of each image into the buffer.  Then print the buffer.  Repeat for each buffer.  This is how many ink jet and laser printers work.

Comment: @Idempotence - thanks for the info. Do you recommend I repost this there now?

Comment: @HologramDesigns You may be able to get a moderator to move it for you, instead of having to delete and repost it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion for randomCheck (I didn't check if it compiles, but hopefully there shouldn't be any problem):

```
void randomCheck()
{
  static string* images[] = {
    Seven, Money, Diamond, Bolt, Cherry, Clover
  };

  static string* wtfs[] = {
    wtf1, wtf2, wtf3, wtf4, wtf5, wtf6, wtf7, wtf8, wtf9
  };

  for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    v[i] = getNum(0, 6);
    string* image = images[v[i]];
    string* wtf = wtfs[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; ++j)
      wtf[j] = image[j];
  }
}
```

Use loops and arrays to reduce code size.

Comment: I'm excited to see if this works! Seems great. Our teacher is awful and gives us these rather advanced projects but doesn't have the knowledge to help us code them efficiently... I'm still not 100℅ confident as to how pointers work, which is obviously great knowledge for these situations. Thanks for the quick reply.